# Как перенести всех пользователей из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

Есть БД с пользователями в таблице `users` (Devise). Нужно их перенести в другую БД в одноименную таблицу.

Rails в текущей стадии работает с двумя БД.

Пробую прогнать обычным массивом, в котором создаю нового пользователя, но получаю ошибку:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank

Это ошибка вполне логичная, ведь по сути я только что попытался зарегистрировать пользователя.

Но как в таком случае создать запись в таблице `users`, игнорируя Devise.

Answer (score 0):

У девайса обязательно заполнить поле password, которая потом захешируется через bcrypt в encrypted_password. 
Тебе нужен простой sql запрос.

Вроде это то, что нужно:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284514/how-do-i-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-postgres-using-copy-command